# In Git, I get an error when I try to delete my local branch

Tags: git, github

I looked around SO, but couldn't find any answer with the error I have.

I created a new branch but I forgot to do something before hand, so I need to delete the new branch I just created from my local machine.
The issue is, when I do `git branch -d <branch_name>` I get this error:
`Cannot delete the branch <branch_name> which you are currently working on.`

But I'm not doing anything in it, I just want to delete it.

What are the steps to follow to delete a local branch and for the error not to come up again?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot delete the *current* branch from under your feet.
Before you can delete a branch, you must switch to a different branch:

```
git checkout other-branch
```